# El menú no se queda fijo sin flotar ni se distribuye a la izquierda y a la derecha CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Básicamente quiero que el menú se me quede fijo pero sin flotar en la página (actualmente flota superponiéndose sobre otros elementos de la web) y además que el Inicio aparezca a la izquierda y el resto de opciones a la derecha. Os paso todo el código:

```js
function desplegarMenu(){

    let ancla=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-enlace"); //Cojo la clase sobre la que quiero actuar. Al ser varios enlaces, lo que estoy creando es un array, que puedo recorrer

    for (let i = 0; i < ancla.length; i++) {
        ancla[i].classList.toggle("desaparece"); //Classlist es una propiedad que me permite manejar las clases de CSS. Con toggle, si sólo hay un parámetro como ahora, le da el valor inverso booleano, es decir: si es true lo pone a false, y si es false lo pone a true.
    }

    let anclaContacto=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-enlace-especifico"); //Cojo la clase sobre la que quiero actuar. Al ser varios enlaces, lo que estoy creando es un array, que puedo recorrer

    for (let i = 0; i < anclaContacto.length; i++) {
        anclaContacto[i].classList.toggle("desaparece"); //Classlist es una propiedad que me permite manejar las clases de CSS. Con toggle, si sólo hay un parámetro como ahora, le da el valor inverso booleano, es decir: si es true lo pone a false, y si es false lo pone a true.
    }


}
```

```css
/* Tipografías */

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px; 
}

h2{
    font-weight: 700;
}

li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Resto de estilos de la página */

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center; 
    padding: 30px 10%; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 100%;
}

/* nav{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-around;
} */

.nav-boton{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: none; 
    border: 2px solid #f4f6ff; 
}

.nav-inicio{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.nav-enlace{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.nav-enlace-especifico{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.contacto{
    background: #fc5185; 
    color: #fff; 
}

.contacto:hover{
    background: #fb044e; 
}

.nav-enlace:hover{
    background: #364f6b;
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}


.precios{
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center; 
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
 
}

.promocioncursos{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000000; 
    margin: 20px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
    max-width: 500px; 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.precio{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #43dde6; 
}

.btn-comprar{
    background: #fc5185; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    left:50%;
    top: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

.seccion-boton-info{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.boton-info{
    background:#fc5185;
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}


button:active{
    background:#c70039;
}

.btn-comprar:hover{
    background:  #FD3F3F; 
}

.boton-info:hover{
    background: #FD3F3F;
}

/* Los media para el diseño responsive */

/* Con esto le digo que entre 0 y 700 px se comporte de una determinada manera y si no, de la forma predeterminada que ya le he dicho yo con CSS */
@media (max-width: 700px){
    nav{
        flex-direction: column; 
    }

    .nav-boton{
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    .nav-enlace{
        margin: 10px 0px; 
    }

    .nav-enlace-especifico{
        margin: 10px 0px; 
    }

    .desaparece{
        display: none; 
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript Academy, tu academia online de JavaScript de referencia</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!--TODO: Intentar echar todo a la derecha en el menú principal. Clase diferente para el inicio. Esto tengo que intentarlo que hoy la he liado -->
    <!--TODO:Fijar barra de arriba: position: fixed; orden de capas css poner capa más adelante. -->
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <button class="nav-boton" onclick="desplegarMenu()">Menú</button>
            <a href="#" class="nav-inicio desaparece">Inicio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Quiénes somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Nuestros cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Accede a tus cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace-especifico desaparece contacto">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="precios">

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Rookie</h2>
            <p class="precio">10€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a los cursos de JavaScript más básicos</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende las bases de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Junior Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">20€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a los cursos de JavaScript básicos + intermedios</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende JS hasta nivel intermedio</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Senior Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">30€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a todos los cursos de JS, hasta nivel avanzado</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Llega hasta los límites de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Premium Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">40€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a TODOS los cursos de JavaScript, más acceso a cursos de todos los frameworks de JavaScript (Node.js, Angular...) </p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende las bases de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend, ahora también en Backend con Node.js</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="seccion-boton-info">
        <button class="boton-info"> QUIERO SABER MÁS </button>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar la propiedad CSS position `sticky` para lograr ese efecto que quiere y `display: grid;` para organizar los elementos.

```js
function desplegarMenu(){

    let ancla=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-enlace"); //Cojo la clase sobre la que quiero actuar. Al ser varios enlaces, lo que estoy creando es un array, que puedo recorrer

    for (let i = 0; i < ancla.length; i++) {
        ancla[i].classList.toggle("desaparece"); //Classlist es una propiedad que me permite manejar las clases de CSS. Con toggle, si sólo hay un parámetro como ahora, le da el valor inverso booleano, es decir: si es true lo pone a false, y si es false lo pone a true.
    }

    let anclaContacto=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-enlace-especifico"); //Cojo la clase sobre la que quiero actuar. Al ser varios enlaces, lo que estoy creando es un array, que puedo recorrer

    for (let i = 0; i < anclaContacto.length; i++) {
        anclaContacto[i].classList.toggle("desaparece"); //Classlist es una propiedad que me permite manejar las clases de CSS. Con toggle, si sólo hay un parámetro como ahora, le da el valor inverso booleano, es decir: si es true lo pone a false, y si es false lo pone a true.
    }


}
```

```css
/* Tipografías */

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px; 
}

h2{
    font-weight: 700;
}

li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Resto de estilos de la página */

header{
  padding: 30px 10% 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: sticky;
   z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav-boton{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: none; 
    border: 2px solid #f4f6ff; 
}

.nav-inicio{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.nav-enlace{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.nav-enlace-especifico{
    background:#fff; 
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.contacto{
    background: #fc5185; 
    color: #fff; 
}

.contacto:hover{
    background: #fb044e; 
}

.nav-enlace:hover{
    background: #364f6b;
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}


.precios{
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center; 
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
 
}

.promocioncursos{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000000; 
    margin: 20px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
    max-width: 500px; 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.precio{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #43dde6; 
}

.btn-comprar{
    background: #fc5185; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    left:50%;
    top: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

.seccion-boton-info{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.boton-info{
    background:#fc5185;
    color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}


button:active{
    background:#c70039;
}

.btn-comprar:hover{
    background:  #FD3F3F; 
}

.boton-info:hover{
    background: #FD3F3F;
}

/* Los media para el diseño responsive */

/* Con esto le digo que entre 0 y 700 px se comporte de una determinada manera y si no, de la forma predeterminada que ya le he dicho yo con CSS */
@media (max-width: 700px){
    nav{
        flex-direction: column; 
    }

    .nav-boton{
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    .nav-enlace{
        margin: 10px 0px; 
    }

    .nav-enlace-especifico{
        margin: 10px 0px; 
    }

    .desaparece{
        display: none; 
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript Academy, tu academia online de JavaScript de referencia</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!--TODO: Intentar echar todo a la derecha en el menú principal. Clase diferente para el inicio. Esto tengo que intentarlo que hoy la he liado -->
    <!--TODO:Fijar barra de arriba: position: fixed; orden de capas css poner capa más adelante. -->
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <button class="nav-boton" onclick="desplegarMenu()">Menú</button>
            <a href="#" class="nav-inicio desaparece">Inicio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Quiénes somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Nuestros cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace desaparece">Accede a tus cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-enlace-especifico desaparece contacto">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="precios">

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Rookie</h2>
            <p class="precio">10€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a los cursos de JavaScript más básicos</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende las bases de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Junior Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">20€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a los cursos de JavaScript básicos + intermedios</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende JS hasta nivel intermedio</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Senior Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">30€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a todos los cursos de JS, hasta nivel avanzado</p>
        <hr>
            <p>Llega hasta los límites de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="promocioncursos">
            <h2>Plan Premium Dev</h2>
            <p class="precio">40€/mes</p>
            <p>Acceso a TODOS los cursos de JavaScript, más acceso a cursos de todos los frameworks de JavaScript (Node.js, Angular...) </p>
        <hr>
            <p>Aprende las bases de JavaScript</p>
            <p>El lenguaje de programación más utilizado en Frontend, ahora también en Backend con Node.js</p>
            <p>Cursos realizados por programadores con años de experiencia en la industria</p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="btn-comprar">Comprar</a>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="seccion-boton-info">
        <button class="boton-info"> QUIERO SABER MÁS </button>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```